# 10K, 20M, 21V kudos etc... in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, rating

I am creating a snippet-site where people can rate snippets, just like votes on SO. Currently, when a snippet has over 999 kudos, it looks like on this mug:
[image: mug]
<sub>(source: [picocool.com](http://picocool.com/images/uploads/img_1705.jpg))</sub>

So what I want is to do a 1K, 1M, etc... kudos like on SO:

```
-----
|999|
-----

**user does +1**
-----
|1K |
-----

**one million kudos**
-----
|1M |
-----
```

The same goes for billions, trillions, quadrillions, quintillions, etc... :'D

Has Ruby got methods for this, and if not, how can I write them myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Ruby has something like this. Rails does have a set of [number helpers](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html), but doesn't include this specific feature. However, if you view source for "number to human size" you should be able to roll your own without much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has been implemented. I suggest you have a look at this patch:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4239-patch-improvements-in-number_helperrb

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create an application-wide helper (application_helper.rb inside app/helpers). You can expand this by using nested if's, but I think you get the idea. I am not saying this is the way to do it, but it beats having something working, than nothing at all.

```
def kudoify(kudos)

if kudos > 1000 && kudos < 1000000 then 
mykudos_prefix = (kudos / 1000 )
mykudos_suffix = (kudos % 1000 )
mykudos = mykudos_prefix.to_s + "K" + mykudos_suffix.to_s
end

return mykudos
end
```